# Terraform correlation to resource with for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using below code to assign defualt subnets to ASG

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_spot_asg" {
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.ids
.... etc...
```

Subnets done via

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "all_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}
```

Below I have aws_autoscaling_policy and I'm stuck on how to relate one to the other

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "ecs_cluster_scale_policy" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_spot_asg.name
```

Getting error:

> Because aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_spot_asg has "for_each" set, its
> attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
>
> For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
> aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_spot_asg[each.key]

How this should be modified ?

Comment: Are you sure you need `for_each`? Woudn't just using `vpc_zone_identifier = data.aws_subnet_ids.ecs_spot_asg.ids` be enough if you want to enable your asg for all subnets?

Comment: It shold be data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.ids, I was constatly trying vpc_zone_identifier = [data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.ids] which was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was adding [] to  vpc_zone_identifier = data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.ids

So instead of  vpc_zone_identifier = [data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.ids] it should be  vpc_zone_identifier = data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.ids